# How to show message box in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, template

How to show the message box in Magento 2 (on the home page). message box working the whole site except for the home page.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to create one `message.phtml` file in `Magento_Theme/html/message.phtml`, than add your code. in layout file - `cms_index_index.xml` inside body tag and add below code :

```
<referenceContainer name="page.messages">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="ajax.message.placeholder" template="Magento_Theme::html/messages.phtml"/>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Messages" name="messages" as="messages" template="Magento_Theme::messages.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

open your Magento 2 theme's **cms_index_index.xml** file  and update with below xml content to insert message 
block into Home page

**File : cms_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
...........................
...........................
    <referenceContainer name="page.messages">
           <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="ajax.message.placeholder" template="Magento_Theme::html/messages.phtml"/>
           <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Messages" name="messages" as="messages" template="Magento_Theme::messages.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
...........................
...........................
    </body>
</page>
```